# R-devel: "object 'checkCompilerOptions' not found" when installing magrittr

Tags: r, bioconductor, magrittr

I've installed R-devel on Ubuntu following [this guide](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-the-development-version-of-r-on-ubuntu-alongside-the-current-version-of-r/). When trying to install magrittr with `install.packages("magrittr")` I'm getting this:

```
* installing *source* package ‘magrittr’ ...
** package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'checkCompilerOptions' not found
Calls: ::: -> get
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/magrittr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpagwvBj/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("magrittr") :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
```

The [single other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048773/checkcompileroptions-error-while-installing-package-littler-docker) refering to this error didn't help me. Can anyone help?

What I'm **really** trying to do is to install the latest development version of the [Gviz](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/html/Gviz.html) package. In order to do that [I must use the development version of bioconductor and R](https://www.bioconductor.org/developers/how-to/useDevel/). Down in the dependency tree for Gviz comes magrittr.

My sessionInfo():

```
R Under development (unstable) (2016-02-18 r70185)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0 tcltk_3.3.0
```

Comment: `checkCompilerOptions` seems to be from the compiler package. Is there anything in your .Rprofile or otherwise that references the compiler? You could try adding `options(error=traceback)` to your .Rprofile to get a sense of the function calls leading to the error.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have nothing in my .Rprofile at all, and adding (or using) `options(error=traceback)` didn't produce a different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install Gviz! This is what got me there:

1. I tried using `devtools::install_github("Bioconductor-mirror/Gviz")` to install Gviz instead of doing it with `biocLite("Gviz")`. This got me the `checkCompilerOptions` error, but now with the package matrixStats.
2. I installed matrixStats using `devtools::install_github("HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats")`. This worked.
3. At this point I tried installing magrittr again, using `install.packages("magrittr")`. It worked somehow!
4. I could now install Gviz with `devtools::install_github("Bioconductor-mirror/Gviz")`

I still have no idea about the `checkCompilerOptions` error, and would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem installing the `raster` package. I found out [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/drd/issues/3) that the problem was a conflict between library directories exported by the second script of the guide you are mentionning:

```
#!/bin/bash
export R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library::/usr/lib/R/library'}
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin:$PATH"
R "$@"
```

So I removed the library folders not related to my R-devel instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
export R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'}
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin:$PATH"
R "$@"
```

And it finally worked.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm unable to test this for a while, but if another person says that this made it work for them (indicating that it's a good solution) I'll accept your answer instead!